# SQL Performance - SSIS takes 2 mins to call a SProc, but SSMS takes <1 sec

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSIS package that fills a SQL Server 2008 R2 DataWarehouse, and when it recreates the DW from scratch, it does several million calls to a stored procedure that does the heavy lifting in terms of calculations.

The problem is that the SSIS package takes days to run and shouldn't take that long.  The key seems to be that when the SSIS package calls the SProc, it takes about 2 minutes for the SProc to return the results.  But if I recreate the call manually (on the same database) it takes <1 sec to return the result, which is what I'd expect.

See this screen shot, in the top is the SQL Profiler Trace showing the call by the SSIS Package taking 130 seconds, and in the bottom is my recreation of the call, taking <1 sec.

http://screencast.com/t/ygsGcdBV

The SProc queries the database, iterates through the results with a cursor, does a lot of calculations on pairs of records, and amalgamates the numbers into 2 results which get returned.

However the timing of the manual call, suggests to me that it's not an issue with the SProc itself, or any indexing issue with the database itself, so why would the SSIS package be taking so much longer than a manual call?

Any hints appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Lots of possibilities here. First and foremost is Parameter Sniffing, followed by different set options. The definitive treatise is  [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) but @PaulWhite has a more concise response on [slow stored proc execution](https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/346/slow-stored-proc-execution-on-log-shipping-seconda.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, but I do have a suggestion and a procedure that can help you get more information for a solution.

Suggestion: a stored proc that gets called millions of times should not be using a cursor. Usually a cursor can be replaced by a few statements and a temp table or two. For temp tables with more than 10k rows or so, index it.

Procedure: At key places in your stored proc put a statement

```
declare @timer1 datetime = GetDate()
(some code)
declare @timer2 datetime = GetDate()
(more code)
declare @timer3 datetime = GetDate()
```

then, at the end:

```
select 
datediff(ss,@timer1,@timer2) as Action1,
datediff(ss,@timer2,@timer3) as Action2
```

At that point, you'll know which part of your query is working differently. I'm guessing you've got an "Aha!" coming.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and for the tip.

I realise that a cursor is less than ideal, however it only iterates through a few dozen rows typically, and is normally very quick, which is why when the SProc is executed manually, it takes less than a second.  I don't think I could improve much on that using temporary tables.

The issue remains that the same code takes 2 minutes when called from SSIS, and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed in debugging the reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the real problem is in your stored procedure, but I've included some basic SSIS items as well to try to fix your problem:

- Ensure connection managers for OLE DB sources are all set toDelayValidation ( = True).
- Ensure that ValidateExternalMetadata is set to false
- DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize to correspond to the table's row sizes
- DROP and Recreate your destination component is SSIS
- Ensure in your stored procedure that SET ANSI_NULLS ON
- Ensure that the SQL in your sproc hits an index
- Add the query hint OPTION (FAST 10000) - This hint means that it will choose a query which will optimise for the first 10,000 rows – the default SSIS buffer size
- Review your stored procedure SQL Server [parameter sniffing](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html).

**Slow way:**

```
create procedure GetOrderForCustomers(@CustID varchar(20))
as
begin
  select * from orders
  where customerid = @CustID
end
```

**Fast way:**

```
create procedure GetOrderForCustomersWithoutPS(@CustID varchar(20))
as
begin
  declare @LocCustID varchar(20)
  set @LocCustID = @CustID

  select * from orders
  where customerid = @LocCustID
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite simple. Verify the indexes in the table. It could be similiar/conflicting indexes and the solution could be to drop one of them. 
With the SQL query in SSMS have a look at the Execution plan and which index object is used. Is it the same for the slow SP?
If they use different indexes try to use the fast one in SP. Example how to:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable WITH (INDEX(IndexName))
WHERE MyIndexedColumn = 0
```